# Is there a keyboard short cut to edit a cell in Numbers?

Tags: keyboard, numbers

Back when I used Excel you could easily do all the navigation and editing on a spreadsheet with the keyboard. I could navigate around with the arrow keys and hit <kbd>F2</kbd> to edit a cell and start typing.

In Numbers '09 I can navigate easily using the arrows then start typing to overwrite the contents of a cell. But I can't figure out how to navigate to a cell and then edit its contents without clicking on the cell with the mouse[1].

**Is there an easy way to do this without the mouse?**

---

1 -  Okay, so I did figure out one way (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>space</kbd>, <kbd>backspace</kbd>, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) but it's such a hack that the mouse starts looking better.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

(<kbd>⌥Option</kbd><kbd>Enter↩</kbd>).

Or just return if you've unchecked *Return key moves to next cell* in the inspector:

[image]

Comment: I can't find this option any more in Numbers 4.0. However, Alt+Enter works anyway.

Comment: If there is a formula in the cell, Control+= will open up the formula editor (as will Option+Return as mentioned).

Answer (score 12):

There are two ways to change the content of a cell using the keyboard:

1. Navigate to the desired cell with the arrow keys and then simply start typing. The previous content of the cell (if there was any) will be replaced.
2. Navigate to the desired cell with the arrow keys and the press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd>. The content of the cell will *not* be replaced and the cursor appears at the end of the cell content.

Comment: I went with Lri's answer because you'd repeated what I'd mentioned in the question about overwriting and they'd added the tip about changing the return key's behavior.

Comment: Still frustrating that there is no option to switch (1) and (2) . I always want to have cursor navigation within my cells.