# What is the Numbers keyboard shortcut to get in the formula bar of a cell?

Tags: keyboard, numbers

I am looking for a keyboard shortcut in Numbers to edit the current cell via the *formula bar* (if that is the right word). Screen shot:

[image]

Please note, I am not looking for [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/34470/23714) answer. That is how to put your cursor in the current cell, and not the formula bar.

Thanks.